# Injectivity and surjectivity of decreasing functions

Tags: functions

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is said to be strictly decreasing if

$$∀x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R, (x_1 < x_2 \implies f(x_1) > f(x_2))$$

Is this function injective? Surjective?

Is it sufficient enough to say that because for all real numbers x, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$ for injectivity?

Also for surjectivity would it suffice to say that because every value in the codomain is hit, it is surjective?

I'm struggling to make this rigorous even though I believe I have the proper intuition.

Comment: You are correct as to injectivity.  For surjectivity:  Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Note:  your argument for injectivity doesn't make sense though your conclusion is correct.  To prove it, just note that if $x\neq y$ then we must have either $x>y$ or $y>x$.  In the first case $f(x)<f(y)$ and in the second case $f(x)>f(y)$ so in neither case are they equal.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks!